# How to extract multiple links within same class in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to extract all the links within the same div class from the following code:

```
<div class='page-numbers clearfix'><span class='current'>
1</span><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/2/' class='inactive'>
2</a><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/3/' class='inactive'>
3</a><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/4/' class='inactive'>
4</a></div>
```

I have tried:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="<div class='page-numbers clearfix'><span class='current'>1</span><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/2/' class='inactive'>2</a><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/3/' class='inactive'>3</a><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/4/' class='inactive'>4</a></div>
"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'page-numbers clearfix'}):
    link= i.find('a', href=True)
    print(link['href'])
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. The output i need is:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/2/

https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/3/

https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/4/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `find_all` while finding `a` tag also. The below code works fine.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

stra = """
<div class='page-numbers clearfix'><span class='current'>
1</span><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/2/' class='inactive'>
2</a><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/3/' class='inactive'>
3</a><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/4/' class='inactive'>
4</a></div>
"""
soup = bs(stra, 'html.parser')
for i in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'page-numbers clearfix'}):
    links = i.find_all('a', href=True)
    for link in links:
        print(link['href'])
```

Output:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/2/
https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/3/
https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/4/
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible (slightly shorter) variation on all the other good answers here:

```
for item in soup.select('div', {'class': 'page-numbers clearfix'}):
   for link in item.select('a', href=True):
       print(link['href'])
```

Comment: one line: links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.page-numbers [href]')]

Comment: @QHarr - Your'e right! Though, strictly speaking, in order to really make it one line, you have to drop the `links=` part, or else you'll have to add a `print` statement to get the output :D

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of the links:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = '''<div class='page-numbers clearfix'><span class='current'>
1</span><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/2/' class='inactive'>
2</a><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/3/' class='inactive'>
3</a><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/4/' class='inactive'>
4</a></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "lxml")

div = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'page-numbers clearfix'})
containers = div.find_all('a', attrs={'class': 'inactive'})
links = [c['href'] for c in containers]
```

`links` returns:

```py
['https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/2/',
 'https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/3/',
 'https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/4/']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
data='''<div class='page-numbers clearfix'><span class='current'>
1</span><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/2/' class='inactive'>
2</a><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/3/' class='inactive'>
3</a><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/4/' class='inactive'>
4</a></div>'''


soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

item= soup.find('div', class_="page-numbers clearfix")
for item in item.find_all('a', href=True):
    print(item['href'])
```

Output:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/2/
https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/3/
https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/4/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<div class='page-numbers clearfix'><span class='current'>
1</span><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/2/' class='inactive'>
2</a><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/3/' class='inactive'>
3</a><a href='https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/4/' class='inactive'>
4</a></div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

for a in soup.select('div.page-numbers.clearfix a[href]'):
    print(a['href'])
```

Prints:

```
https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/2/
https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/3/
https://www.example.com/blog/author/abc/page/4/
```